# jquery fetching blank value from input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms

i have a form where it have 2 input and 1 texatarea, when a user submit the form the default behavior of the form is stopped to make the way for ajax request. here is the code i am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#submit').click(function(){
        $name = $('input#name').val();
        alert($name);
    return false;
    });
});
```

and here is my html form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="mail-form">
    <label for="name">Name *</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
    <label for="email">Email *</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
    <label for="message">Message *</label><br/>
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

when i click submit buttons it just displays blank value in alert box even if i enter some value in name field. whereas if i use the following code for form.

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="yourname"/>
```

it display yourname in alert box properly. what is wrong with my code?

UPDATE :

Here is my whole [index.html](http://jsfiddle.net/MknfR/) (http://jsfiddle.net/MknfR/)file, is there anything wrong with DOM?

Comment: Did you mean to have $name ?  I know when I'm working on php and Javascript at the same time, it sometimes sneaks in there, but it's hard to tell if it's a glitch when you're using JQuery.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/p4rTG/

Comment: please have a look at my post, i have updated my post with the link to index.html file, i doubt if it has something to do with DOM??

Comment: @Ibrahim Even this seems to be working alright: http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/MknfR/3/ - the only change I made was to move your `bxslider` code after the `click` handler since that script isn't loaded with the fiddle

Comment: lol, this is interesting, yes it works in jsfiddle without any problem i tested it. but i can guarantee it does not work on my browser, tested in chrome, firexox and safari on OSX 10.6.6

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying your page by removing everything extra except for jQuery, ensuring it works then and then adding your external JS files and the functionality one by one until something breaks.

Comment: good idea, thanks, ill try it out tomorrow too tired to check it now :), thanks for your help..

Comment: Try some debugging on your code. Put some alert until it reached the function that you need. Did you use some developer tools? if not use firebug or in chrome the developers tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird. It works great. Test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/PLm5a/.

Please, test it by yourself with that link to be sure that it doesn't come from your development environment.

Regards

Comment: i have updated my post with the link to my index.html. it doesn't work for me at all. can something be wrong with the dom. incase you want to look at my index.html file here is the link. http://jsfiddle.net/MknfR/

Comment: I tried your code. I removed the included js/css files (main and the bxslider plugin as they are unreachable). The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PLm5a/1/

Comment: lol, this is interesting, yes it works in jsfiddle without any problem i tested it. but i can guarantee it does not work on my browser, tested in chrome, firexox and safari on OSX 10.6.6

Comment: @Ibrahim: I'm pretty sure that it comes from errors in the plugin/main files. Anyway, the code I edited should work on any jQuery compatible browser.

Comment: @Zakria, yes that is what i am wondering too, i guess ill have to use plain js instead of jquery for form validation and ajax request for sending mails. i hope atleast that works properly.. :) it is already 2:30 am here in bangalore too tired to check it now. i will try it tomorrow. anyway thanks for your help i highly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a blank value attribute to the HTML source:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
```